# jQuery user input and show different result

Tags: javascript

I am the newbie of javascript.

I want to make a website that can show the different result from user input.

For example,

User can input `dog`, and I show the dog img to the user. (the image already exists)

Now, I know how to show the image by the default value to the javascript.

But I hope I can get the user input and then give this value to the javascript, then show the result.

How can I make this?

Really need your help, thank you.

Comment: how does the image already exist?

Comment: I have saved the image in my computer, and the name of image is the same as user input.

Comment: And you want the user to describe the picture?

Comment: Yes, let the user input and show the matching image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/JS_input_change_image/edit

```
<input id="userInput" tyle="text">  
<img id="theImage" src="folder/default.jpg">
```

JS:

```
function $el(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function getImage(){ 
  $el('theImage').src = "folder/"+ this.value +".jpg"
}
$el('userInput').addEventListener('input', getImage, false );
```

- The function `$el( id )` is just a reusable function that helps us to get a desired element
- When a user creates on our `#userInput` an `"input"` event, we just call our `getImage()` function.
- The `getImage` function for it's bound to an element will refer to that element's `this.value` to get the inputted value and accordingly change the image `src` of our `#theImage` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

<sub>This is just to get you started, in the future try to add in your question what you've already tried - so we can start to help from somewhere or give you more suggestions about your code.</sub>

Comment: Really thank you! I'll try to figure it out. And thanks to your suggestion, I will add question more clearly in the future.